# how to copy the dynamic file name and append some string while copying into other directory in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have many files like `ABC_Timestamp.txt` , `RAM_Timestamp.txt`here timestamp will be different everytime. I want to copy this file into other directory but while copying I want append one string at the end of the file , so the format will be `ABC_Timestamp.txt.OK` and `RAM_Timestamp.txt.OK`. How to append the string in dynamic file. Please suggest.

Comment: "I want append one string at the end of the file" - the people are confused. "At the end of file" is something entirely different than "at the end of the filename". Please clarify :/

Comment: I apologise for creating this confusion. I want to append the string at the end of the filename while copying the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say:

```
for i in *.txt; do cp "${i}" targetdirectory/"${i}".OK ; done
```

or

```
for i in ABC_*.txt RAM_*.txt; do cp "${i}" targetdirectory/"${i}".OK ; done
```

Comment: This doesn't append one string at the end of the file

Comment: @sehe The question doesn't appear to be about *modifying* the file, it's about modifying the *file name*.

Comment: I didn't say it was about modifying the file (it's clearly about copying the file). But, granted you may be on to something. We'll let the OP clarify (even though the question is not at all ambiguous as posed)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 pence:

```
(cat file.txt; echo "append a line"; date +"perhaps with a timestamp: %T") > file.txt.OK
```

Or more complete for your filenames:

```
 while sleep 3;
 do
    for a in ABC RAM
    do
        (echo "appending one string at the end of the file" | cat ${a}_Timestamp.txt -) > ${a}_Timestamp.txt.OK
    done
 done
```

Comment: can you suggest one liner solution and I am not aware of the timestamp while will be there on filename ? Static part of the file name is ABC and RAM.

Comment: @Pooja25 So it's about modifying the filename and not the contents of the file?

Comment: @Pooja25 Do clarify the question first. Then see how the answer works. Once you know how it words, you could go on and condense it into a oneliner. Oneliners have no merit unless you know what you're doing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this on command line.

```
ls -1|awk '/ABC_.*\.txt/||/RAM_.*\.txt/
          {old=$0;
           new="/new_dir/"old".OK";
           system("cp "old" "new); }'
```

Taken from [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename)

Comment: This must be one strange use of the word "Simply" that I was previously unaware of

Answer (score -1):

How about first dumping the names of the file in another file and then moving file one by one.

```
  find . -name "*.txt" >fileNames


  while read line
  do
  newName="${line}appendText"
  echo $newName
  cp $line $newName
  done < fileNames
```

Comment: It is not about moving. If that were the case, then `rename 's/$/.OK/` *.txt` and or `qmv` would be far better choices

Comment: I have edited to cp. Crux is to append something and move/copy or whatever you want.