# bash: How to transfer/copy only the file names to separate similar files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've some files in a folder A which are named like that:

```
001_file.xyz
002_file.xyz
003_file.xyz
```

in a separate folder B I've files like this:

```
001_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx
002_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx
003_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx
```

Now I want to rename, if possible, with just a command line in the bash all the files in folder B with the file names in folder A. The file extension must stay different.
There is exactly the same amount of files in each folder A and B and they both have the same order due to numbering.

I'm a total noob, but I hope some easy answer for the problem will show up.

Thanks in advance!

ZVLKX

*Example edited for clarification

Comment: It's easy enough (sorta -- there are a lot of details you aren't specifying; are `FILE` and `file` two constant strings, or do the names need to be individually matched together to get them right? Are the extensions always constant?), but it's also not a software development question. Consider https://superuser.com/ rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you Charles. Sorry for posting at the wrong platform.

I just found a [slightly similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712414/how-to-copy-the-dynamic-file-name-and-append-some-string-while-copying-into-othe) here, so I tried asking too.

`FILE` and `file` are actually not constant but the files doesn’t have to be matched together, because they are already numbered correctly. So the first file in B needs to be renamed with the file name of the first file in A and so on.

Comment: ...I mean, if you just wanted to anything matching the regex `FILE_(.*)_([[:digit:]])+.zyx` to `file_\2.xyz` (where `\2` is the second group in the regex match on the original name), that's 100% trivial, and the `rename` command that ships with many OS distros will do it out-of-the-box.

Comment: If the names differ, be sure you reflect that in your test data so people don't write answers that rely on patterns in your test data that aren't reflected in your live data!

Comment: Ok, I got that. My example is not precise in that matter.
A better one might be:


Folder A:

`001_file.xyz`
`002_file.xyz`
`003_file.xyz`

Folder B:

`001_FILE_random.zyx`
`002_FILE_random.zyx`
`003_FILE_random.zyx`


I’m also sure the `rename` or `cp` command will do the job, I just don’t know how to use them on multiple files in different locations. I tried to figure it out, but without results until now and I couldn’t find any example for my use-case.

Comment: I need the simple code for: “take the file name of file #x in A and rename file #x in B with this file name; do that for all n files in A and B”.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: edit your Q sample data, don't expect people to read thru a chain of comments to get the details of what you're trying to do, please! ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @ZVLKX, doesn't my answer already do that? If it doesn't meet your needs, explain *exactly* why and how. And as shellter says -- edit the question to be unambiguously descriptive of your problem.

Comment: @charles-duffy Thank you **very** much so far.
I already learnt a lot within the last hour.

Your script is running, but unfortunately it _doesn’t_ rename the example as mentioned below, or my actual files. There is also no output of the `printf` command. I’m trying to figure out why.

Comment: @ZVLKX, my example actually contains test code you can copy-and-paste. Do you get the same output given for the test code when you copy-and-paste it into an interactive shell, and thereby run it yourself? If so, then you can start by **modifying the example in your question** to include a test that my answer fails with -- I've already given you a test it succeeds with, so modify that to be more like your real use case until it no longer works.

Comment: @ZVLKX, ...by the way, you *are* using my answer by sourcing (or copying/pasting) the function into your shell... right? [To be entirely clear, that's the way it's intended to be used; you could also use the function body as the body of a script -- after adding a shebang -- but you'd want to take out the declaration in that case].

Comment: @charles-duffy, I get the output of the `printf` command now (I previously didn’t configured the bash script correctly). If I uncomment the line `mv "$f" "$forFilesFromDir/$destName.$f_ext"` the output is the same, but no files are renamed.

I edited the example in my question so it now represents _exactly_ the use-case. I’m now testing an other example with folders X and Y and the actual files, to check if your script edit them.

Comment: @ZVLKX, ahh -- my answer expect the numbers to be at the end of the name, not the front, since that's how your original question was written. Providing representative sample data is important.

Comment: @ZVLKX, ...as for the claim that you got the same behavior after uncommenting the `mv`, I frankly don't believe you -- if `mv` hadn't worked, it would have at least written an error to stderr. The reasonable expectation, then, is that the modified function didn't get successfully defined in the shell you were testing in. That said, if you want to prove the point, capture a log that includes stderr when running the script, as modified, with `set -x` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation might look a bit like this:

```
renameFromDir() {
  useNamesFromDir=$1
  forFilesFromDir=$2

  for f in "$forFilesFromDir"/*; do

    # Put original extension in $f_ext
    f_ext=${f##*.}

    # Put number in $f_num
    f_num=${f##*/}; f_num=${f_num%%_*}

    # look for a file in directory B with same number
    set -- "$useNamesFromDir"/"${f_num}"_*.*
    [[ $1 && -e $1 ]] || {
      echo "Could not find file number $f_num in $dirB" >&2
      continue
    }
    (( $# > 1 )) && {
      # there's more than one file with the same number; write an error
      echo "Found more than one file with number $f_num in $dirB" >&2
      printf '  - %q\n' "$@" >&2
      continue
    }

    # extract the parts of our destination filename we want to keep
    destName=${1##*/}       # remove everything up to the last /
    destName=${destName%.*} # and past the last .

    # write the command we would run to stdout
    printf '%q ' mv "$f" "$forFilesFromDir/$destName.$f_ext"; printf '\n'
    ## or uncomment this to actually run the command
    # mv "$f" "$forFilesFromDir/$destName.$f_ext"
  done
}
```

---

Now, how would we test this?

```
mkdir -p A B
touch A/00{1,2,3}_file.xyz B/00{1,2,3}_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx
renameFromDir A B
```

Given that, the output is:

```
mv B/001_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx B/001_file.zyx
mv B/002_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx B/002_file.zyx
mv B/003_FILE_somerandomtext.zyx B/003_file.zyx
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't helpful, but I had fun writing it.

This renames items in folder B to the names in folder A, preserving the extension of B.

```
A_DIR="./A"
A_FILE_EXT=".xyz"
B_DIR="./B"
B_FILE_EXT=".zyx"

FILES_IN_A=`find $A_DIR -type f -name *$A_FILE_EXT`
FILES_IN_B=`find $B_DIR -type f -name *$B_FILE_EXT`

for A_FILE in $FILES_IN_A
do
    A_BASE_FILE=`basename $A_FILE`
    A_FILE_NUMBER=(${A_BASE_FILE//_/ })
    A_FILE_WITHOUT_EXTENSION=(${A_BASE_FILE//./ })

    for B_FILE in $FILES_IN_B
    do
        B_BASE_FILE=`basename $B_FILE`
        B_FILE_NUMBER=(${B_BASE_FILE//_/ })

        if [ ${A_FILE_NUMBER[0]} == ${B_FILE_NUMBER[0]} ]; then
            mv $B_FILE $B_DIR/$A_FILE_WITHOUT_EXTENSION$B_FILE_EXT
            break
        fi
    done

done
```

Comment: Consider running this through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues identified there. There are some additional problems beyond that, though --

Comment: ...if you create a file with a space in its name in either `A` or `B` directories, you'll see that `FILES_IN_A` and `FILES_IN_B` split the content on either side of the space into two separate words. See, on that point, entry #1 in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Similarly, expanding a string into an array based on word splitting (as you're doing here) isn't safe, because legitimate filenames can contain any character other than NUL. The safe way to read output from `find` into an array is by using `print0` to generate a NUL-delimited stream, as in `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do array+=( "$filename" ); done < <(find A -type f -print0)`

Comment: Also, `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside POSIX `test`. If you read [the relevant standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), you'll note that `=` is the only specified/compliant string comparison operator.

Comment: Also, all-caps variable names are bad form -- POSIX naming convention for environment variables specifies that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the system or shell, and that names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. Because setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable automatically exports that variable to the environment (overwriting the preexisting shell variable), this naming convention thus applies to shell variables as well.